# How to insert a new Word style into a RMarkdown file

Tags: ms-word, styles, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a simple way to do this using Knitr without using Pandoc?  I tried adding some HTML `<DIV Class="newStyle>&nbsp</div>` into an .Rmd file, but the style didn't show up in the generated Word .docx.

Thanks, Sue.

Comment: I've been trying to add a pagebreak to Word using RStudio, knitr and Pandoc for 2 days now.  I am new to all this, but it seems that there are three possible methods,

Comment: 1.  To use Pandoc's stated ability to define a `<div>` or `<span>` with the attribute `custom-style="myStyleName"`, pandoc will apply the specified style name to the contained elements.  The style name will appear in the resultant .docx.  If it is defined in the reference.docx, it will be used unchanged, if not, it will created from the `body` style.  See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles-in-docx-output.  But this doesn't happen using RStudio and knitr.

Comment: 2. To write your own filter.  Using this discussion as a guide, http://pandoc-discuss.narkive.com/BNVcQyvb/how-to-get-a-page-break-f-from-markdown-docx, but not knowing Haskell, I got a NodeJS filter to work on Windows using `mvhenderson`'s `pandoc-filter`. This inserted some text into the .docx file, 
   `if ( ... ) { return Para(  [ { t: "Str" , c: "PageBreak"  } ] ); }` 
But constructing a RawBlock this way:   
   `if ( ... ) { return RawBlock( '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>', "openxml" ) }` 
did not work.  Does anyone know what the correct syntax would be in NodeJS?

Comment: 3. Use one of the existing styles that Pandoc creates for the standard markdown elements.  Then use a `reference.docx' to redefine one of the styles to format a paragraph with `Page break before` on the Heading 4 style, for instance.  But this is not too practical given than I may only want a pagebreak before one of the H4 headings.

Comment: Bye the way, putting `\pagebreak` into RStudio's Rmarkdown text, produces a pagebreak in a PDF file, and putting `<style> .Pagebreak { page-break-after: always; } </style>` followed by `<div class="Pagebreak"></div>` produces a pagebreak in a HTML file.

Comment: 4. Of course, there is the solution of placing some text into the document, e.g. <div class="Pagebreak">&#160; &#160;&#160</div>, and writing a vba macro subroutine in the reference document that finds all occurrences of the text "&#160; &#160;&#160" and replaces it with a Word page break.  I chose the string of non-printable non-breaking spaces so that it would not be seen when the .Rmd file is converted to PDF or HTML.

Answer (score 3):

My setup: Office 365 Pro Plus, RStudio 1.0.143.

I was able to get both the `<div>` and `<span>` syntax to work. First I created a new style in my reference.docx document with the same name I intended to use in the Pandoc markup tags. Careful what you name the style -- this worked when I used the name "SpanAdd" but did not work with the name "Span_Add." The `<div>` tag should be used when you want to specify a paragraph style -- the default "Linked Paragraph and Character" style type in Word works fine for this. However, the `<span>` tag is more finicky and I was only able to get it to work with a "Character" style type. I based my character styles on "Default Paragraph Text."

Anyway, once I modified a new style in the reference document and saved it, I was able to use these tags within an .Rmd file to generate marked-up text.